# Anyone know an embedable map widget that can be posted to anonymously

Tags: wordpress, mapping, embedded-resource

I am trying to embed a map widget into a wordpress blog.

Visitors to the blog should be able to place a marker on the map and others should be able to view places that other people have marked.

It should not require people to log in before placing a marker.

Can anyone recommend such a service?

Answer (score 0):

Just found http://mapservices.org - seems to be working great so far.